# JQuery .param() method for Angular 2?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, angular

Is there anything like this [$.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) function from JQuery for Angular2?

I know Angular 1 specifically has a service like it, [Angular1 Equivalent](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike)

I have checked the Angular 2 site [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#send-data-to-the-server) and they have a demo of a POST but they send a JSON in the body of the request.

My current, non working, attempt

```
saveEdits() {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    this._http.post("ajax/update-thingy", JSON.stringify(this.dataJson), options)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .toPromise()
        .catch(this.handleError);
    // update in Angular 1 using JQuery function
    // $http({
    //     method : 'POST',
    //     url  : 'ajax/update-thingy',
    //     data : $.param($scope.formData),
    //     headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    // }); 
}

extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    if (body === 'failed') {
        body = [];
    }
    return body || [];
}
private handleError(error: any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead

    return Promise.reject(errMsg);
}
```

Or if it is easier to get JQuery in my Angular2 maybe that is a way to go.

**UPDATE**

I did solve my own issue. Please see my answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39540320/2593877)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my own issue.

Here is what I did, I used [URLSearchParams](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html) from Angular 2. It has worked out pretty well. Not at all complicated and easy to use.

```
import { Headers, RequestOptions, Http, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

saveEdits() {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let params: URLSearchParams = this.serialize(this.myObj);
    this._http.post("ajax/update-thingy", params, options)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .toPromise()
        .catch(this.handleError);
    this.selectedBill = null;
}

serialize(obj: any) {
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();


    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var element = obj[key];

            params.set(key, element);
        }
    }

    return params;
}
```

Comment: careful, URLSearchParams in not supported in all browsers, you need  a polyfill for some of them

Answer (score 2):

There is a built in serialize function, but its not exported..
So we need to go a little workaround..

You could do it like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/ffoaMVbwSOIX5YNLo2ip?p=preview

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlSegment, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{way1}}</h2>
      <h2>{{way2}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  private way1: string;
  private way2: string;

  constructor() {

    let myParams = {you: 'params', will: 'be', here: '!!'};

    // way 1
    let serializer = new DefaultUrlSerializer();
    let nackedUrlTree = serializer.parse('');
    nackedUrlTree.queryParams = myParams;

    this.way1 = 'way1: ' + serializer.serialize(nackedUrlTree);

    // way 2
    let urlSeg = new UrlSegment('', myParams);

    this.way2 = 'way2: ' + urlSeg;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Very slick way to do it! I would have probably used `way1`. Thanks dude!

Comment: Nice! You missed a comma in way 2, so it should be `new UrlSegment('', myParams);`